# Allowable states for a particle in a box

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Assume we have a particle in one dimensional box, say length $ L $ and the potential is given by:

$$ V\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
0 & 0<x<L\\
\infty & else
\end{cases} $$

Then we know that the wave function would be $ \psi\left(x\right)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\sin\left(kx\right) $ Where $ k=\frac{\pi}{L}n $ , and $ n=1,2,3,.... $.

The intuition I had for the allowable values of $ n $ is that $ E=\frac{\hbar^{2}k^{2}}{2m}=\frac{\hbar^{2}\pi^{2}}{2mL^{2}}n^{2} $ and thus $n\geq 1 $, because for $n=0 $ there is no particle.

But I wonder what would be the case when we consider the same problem but the 2D case. That is, the potential is given by: $$ V\left(x,y\right)=\begin{cases}
0 & 0<x<L,\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace0<y<L\\
\infty & else
\end{cases} $$

And now the wave function would be $ \psi\left(x,y\right)=\frac{2}{L}\sin\left(k_{x}x\right)\sin\left(k_{y}y\right) $

Where $ k_{x}=\frac{n\pi}{L},\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace k_{y}=\frac{m\pi}{L} $ and the energies given by:

$ E_{n,m}=\frac{\hbar^{2}\pi^{2}}{2mL^{2}}\left(n^{2}+m^{2}\right) $.

In this case, I cant see why wouldnt we allow $ k=\left(k_{x},k_{y}\right) $ to take values such $ \left(0,1\right) $ or $ \left(1,0\right)$.

But at least according to the way that I solved this problem, I assumed that $ \psi\left(x,y\right)=\psi_{x}\left(x\right)\psi_{y}\left(y\right) $ and actually solved for each coordinate seperatly, so that $k_x$ and $k_y$ in the seperated solution takes values $1,2,3,...$.

So the question is, what value do we allow $ k=\left(k_{x},k_{y}\right) $ to take in this case? would it be $ \left\{ \left(k_{x},k_{y}\right):k_{x}\geq1\in\mathbb{N},k_{y}\geq1\in\mathbb{N}\right\}  $ or maybe the only constraint is that we have to make sure $ E_{n,m}\neq0 $ (and in this case we allow states as $(0,1), (1,0) $).

Thanks in advance

Comment: One wants the wavefunction to vanish at the edges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the one-dimensional square well, the solution with $k=0$ is

$$
\psi(x) = \sqrt{\frac 2L} \sin(0\cdot x) = 0
$$

There is no way to normalize this solution to have $\int \mathrm dx \ \left|\psi\right|^2 = 1$, which is required to interpret $|\psi|^2$ as a probability density.  That's why the allowed principal quantum numbers start with $n=1$.

For the two-dimensional square well, you have this constraint in both dimensions.